# Can we define the value of "this" in all javascript methods?

Tags: javascript

So I have a backbone View and I have this method

```
inscription: function() {
    var self = this;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    //I need to use self here because the context of this function
    //is not my Backbone View
```

How can I use *this* in the getCurrentPosition callback?

Comment: You can use `.bind()` to create a function that uses the value of "self".

Comment: Your question is "can we define the context in all javascript methods". No, you can't, and wouldn't want to. But you can define it in one. Note that you can also pass arguments to `Array.prototype.forEach` and friends to specify the context of the callback.

Comment: A function's *this* parameter is not "context". It is one parameter of a function's [**execution context**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10) that is set by the call or by using *bind*.

Comment: any reason why you're not just using self?

Comment: Because I don't find it clean :\.

Answer (score 0):

Use [_.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) - `_.bind(fn, context)` in your case:

```
var self = this;
//...
var somefn = _.bind(function(position) {
   var self = this;
   //this/self refer to outer this
}, self)
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(somefn)
```

Comment: I recommend using the ECMAScript 5-defined [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ([shimmed](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) as required). I think underscore is really good for some things .. but not this.

Comment: Oh yes, that is using underscore? I have used this methode before, now I understand, thank you!

Comment: @user2864740 `underscore` provides fallbacks if `.bind` is not present in the browser. I recommended `_.bind` because he's using `backbone` and `underscore` is a dependency

Comment: Yes, thats true for his original question as well, unless he was looking to do it with an already declared function

Comment: I don't understand why `self` is necessary at all in the code you show. One advantage of using `bind` is that it reduces the need to use `self`.